# FCSA number does not validate a negative number if assigned by the controller

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, angularjs-validation

I'm working with [FCSA number](https://github.com/FCSAmerica/angular-fcsa-number)
If I enter a negative number in the input, the validation works correctly but if I value the variable ng-model from the controller, the validation is not working.

Why?

```
            <input required
                   class="form-control"
                   name="qta"
                   fcsa-number="{preventInvalidInput: true, min: 1, max:{{c._source.total}}, maxDecimals:0 }"
                   type="text"
                   id="qta"
                   ng-model="c._source.qtaSelected">
```

Here I put a negative number manually:
[image: Here I put a negative number manually]
Here I put a negative number from the controller:
[image: Here I put a negative number from the controller]

With this problem does not work validation ($ valid) of AngularJs

Comment: I think it should be `fcsa-number="{preventInvalidInput: true, min: 1, max:c._source.total, maxDecimals:0 }"` shouldn't use `{{}}` interpolation

Comment: Thanks @pankajparker, but I think not

Comment: could you create a plunkr of it? are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Hi... this is a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/ua2PSNQCOOsp2vbnju15